# Enable stack canaries in Visual Studio Code

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, appsweep

I have an Android apk created from a Flutter project. I have uploaded the apk to AppSweep and it returns the following issue: Native code is compiled without stack canaries.

As a recommendation, AppSweep suggests to compile native code with the **-fstack-protector-all** flag to enable stack canaries.

How can I use this flag in Visual Studio Code to compile a Flutter project?

Answer (score 0):

In your `android/app/build.gradle`

add this flag as:

```
release {
    // other configurations...
    ndk {
        // other ndk configurations...
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        cppFlags += "-fstack-protector-all"
    }
}
```